# Javascript onFocus triggers on page load

Tags: javascript, onfocus

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96qdaytn/)

So I'm having this problem.

I have a simple form:

```
<form method="post" action="login.php">

<input type="text" name="Username" value="Username" />
<input type="password" name="Password" value="Password" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in" />

</form>
```

And this script:

```
function focus(element) {

    console.log('focused ' + element.getAttribute('name'));

    var elementValue = element.value;
    var elementName = element.getAttribute('name');
    elementValue = (elementValue == elementName ? '' : elementValue);

}


var fields = ['Username', 'Password'];

for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {

    console.log(i + ': ' + fields[i]);

    var input = document.getElementsByName(fields[i])[0];

    console.log('input value: ' + input.value);

    input.onFocus = focus(input);

}
```

It is supposed to create **Focus** event listeners for every of the inputs and call **focus()** function as user clicks on any of the fields. But for some reason, as console shows, it just calls the function once a loop for every of the fields and just stops not responding to future **Focus** events.

So my guess is there's something wrong with this line `input.onFocus = focus(input);`, but I don't know what. What am I missing?

Comment: `input.addEventListener('focus', focus, false);` and use `this` in the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the line below, you're calling the `focus` function immediately and passing the return value (which is `undefined`). You also need to use `onfocus` not `onFocus` because the property name is case sensitive.

```
input.onFocus = focus(input);
```

Instead, you can use [`.bind()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) like so:

```
input.onfocus = focus.bind(null, input);
```

This will setup the function with the argument set, without actually calling it.

**[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/96qdaytn/2/)**

Comment: Ok, thank you. I need to learn about this bind() method though, cause I don't quite understand the mechanics.

Comment: No problem, glad it helped. Click on the link I provided to `.bind()`, the MDN docs explain it really well, but basically it allows you to assign a function which has its this context and argument list pre-configured, without actually calling it.

Comment: Yep. Now I got it. Took a minute.

Answer (score 0):

Because instead of assigning the `focus` *function* as the handler of the `onFocus` event, you're assigning its *returned value* (which is `undefined`).

Try this instead:

```
input.onfocus = focus.bind(input, input);
```

Or

```
input.onfocus = function() { focus(input);
```

Also, you need to change `onFocus` to `onfocus`.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onfocus)